# Regex doesn't recognize underscore ( _ ) as special character

Tags: regex

My Regex requirements

- Includes 1 Uppercase Letter
- Includes 1 Lowercase Letter
- Includes 1 Number digit
- Includes 1 Special Character

```
(/^(?=^.{8,40}$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*\W+)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!^.*\n).*$/)
```

However, if I type in `1234ABcd_` the validation fails, only `_` seems doesn't recognized as special characters. Any solutions on my regex? Thanks!

Comment: There's no `_` in your regex. Maybe that should be your angle of attack :-)

Comment: There's no part of this regex that checks for "special characters", however you define those. There's a `\W`, which checks for non-"word" characters, but that's not the same thing as whatever concept of "special characters" you're using.

Comment: Underscore is considered a word character, so it's not included in `\W`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're using `(?=.*\W+)` to match special characters. But `_` is a word character that's in `\w`, and `\W` is everything else, so this doesn't match `_`. Change it to: `(?=.*[\W_]+)`

Also, you don't need `+` in this. You only need to match 1 to be successful.